# How to access drawable resources (color) in java

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to access color resource defined as drawable resource and desire to toggle the background color in JAVA, basically background of a button was changed using below mentioned drawable XML. I tried accessing button and modify color attribut but this changed the shape of button to normal square shape. I want to keep shape as defined in drawable XML and change background color  manually.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#EAEAEA" />

        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
             android:bottomRightRadius="1dip"
             android:topLeftRadius="1dip" 
             android:topRightRadius="8dip" />
    </shape>
    </item>

<item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#EAEA00" />

        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip" 
            android:bottomRightRadius="1dip" 
            android:topLeftRadius="1dip" 
            android:topRightRadius="8dip" />
    </shape>
     </item>
```

Comment: i guess u need to add @color/"whatevercolor it is " and add this in your button xml

Comment: I am not sure how to do this, is there any sample code which points to this? Thanks

Comment: android:color="@android:color/black" . _Hope it helps_

Comment: My question was more on how to control parameters defined in XML through Java code? I mean '<solid android:color="#EAEA00" />' this defined between <selector> and <item> , how can I access this color parameter from Java code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities:

- `myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.CHOOSE_ONE);`
- `myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.youCustomColor);`

If you want to set the color from an hexadecimal value just use the static method of the `Color` class:

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#RRGGBB"));
//http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29
```

Comment: My question was more on how to control parameters defined in XML through Java code? I mean '<solid android:color="#EAEA00" />' this defined between <selector> and <item> , how can I access this color parameter from Java code?

Comment: When I try using a custom color I defined in XML I get an error. And my Eclipse ADT forces me to use a format like: `myTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycustomXMLcolor));` Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to change the color of button -

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
```

and get rgb values from below link -

http://www.ceveni.com/2009/08/set-rgb-color-codes-for-android-and-rgb.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Resource Color You should probably resolve it with `getResources().getColor(R.color.example_color)`

For this option, your code would be the following:

```
myButton.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getColor(R.color.example_color));
```